# Output New Query from Form

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to make a form that changes Query
Example (HTML)

```
<form action="change.php" method="POST" name="Update">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="Enter New Criteria" name="where" >
      <input type="text" value="Enter New Criteria" name="where2" >
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-family:Calibri">
    <input type="submit"  value="Search"/>
  </tr>
</table>
```

SQL Query

```
$Query = "SELECT order_number
          FROM order_header
          WHERE (order_number LIKE **'%CHANGE VALUE HERE%'**
          OR order_number LIKE **'%CHANGE VALUE HERE%'**
```

How would I go about doing that, i'm a complete rookie but I am trying. I tried a search but maybe I'm not using the correct key words.

Comment: try to use prepared statement

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_POST['where']` and `$_POST['where2']` in place of `%CHANGE VALUE HERE%`. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

For example:

```
$Query = "SELECT order_number
          FROM order_header
          WHERE (order_number LIKE '$_POST[where]'
          OR order_number LIKE '$_POST[where2]')";
```

When you've got it working, have a read about SQL Injection: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Note: Instead the query statement quotes, the correct syntax for values is as follows: `'$_POST[where2]'`, as opposed to the usual `$_POST['where2']`.  Watch out, it's very confusing!

Comment: Thanks, Will this create a permanent change or just a temporary change. I want to use the form to create a permanent change in the create.php file.

Comment: This won't be a permanent change to the php file - it will change the value in your database. `$_POST` is an array containing variables, which can be different every time.

Comment: @eternityhq Why would you want to do that, rather leaving the PHP code in a dynamic form, allowing you to use the same PHP no matter what the values in the form?

Comment: @jegesh The reason I want a permanent change is because this is a back end of another screen. The first screen shows the user a list of Orders in two separate columns. But, from time to time that data changes, so to separate the correct data between the columns I need to change what information is being queried for each.

Comment: Why don’t you just write an answer that’s not vulnerable to SQL injection instead of mentioning it in passing?

Comment: Because that wasn't the question, and it makes more sense if you read up on it rather than just get handed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$where = $_POST['where'];
$where2 = $_POST['where2'];

$Query = "SELECT order_number
          FROM order_header
          WHERE (order_number LIKE '%whereParameter%'
          OR order_number LIKE '%where2Partameter%'"

$Query = str_replace("whereParameter", $where, $QueryTemplate);
$Query = str_replace("where2Parameter", $where2, $QueryTemplate);
```

Comment: Why don't just use `'$where'` and `'$where2'` as values in the WHERE statement?  No need to add an extra step that has a potential for syntax errors and has no added value.

Comment: Very valid point! Noted. I will give all these suggestions a whirl and get back to you all.